# iPhone viewport confusion / window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, viewport

I'm having trouble fitting a site to the iphone's screen dimensions.

What I am doing is the following: I have a slideshow with a few pictures running fullscreen in the back of the page and and little text on top.

When I set up the slideshow I do the following:

```
$('#bg').css('width', window.innerHeight).css('height', window.innerWidth);
```

Then I insert the Slideshow and scale and crop the pictures accordingly. This works perfectly fine in all desktop based browsers. Yet, the iPhone does not return its actual screen size but a value of 5000 so I get a rather big slideshow. The rest of the layout seems to render perfectly fine according to the given CSS.

I do know about the viewport "thing" with the iPhone and have already read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html which led me to inserting the following meta-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />
```

Yet again, this does not make any difference, the iPhone will still return a dimension of 5000px.

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so what did the trick for me was using this combination of meta-tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try width=device-width in the meta tag - and make sure you dont have any other elements that are 5000px wide.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this & this led me to have the device return a correct width value in portrait mode, but somehow the values are still messed up in landscape mode?